# T-SQL Desc Limit Sql Syntax

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, visual-studio-2012

I am having trouble with LIMIT DESC clause in my SQL statement. I am currently testing query using the database in Visual Studio 2012.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
    p.id, p.name, pc.categoryName, p.inventoryQuantity 
FROM 
    dbo.Products p 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.ProductVariants pv ON pv.product = p.id 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.ProductCategories pc ON p.productCategory = pc.id 
WHERE 
    pc.categoryName = 'Diary' 
ORDER BY 
    p.inventoryQuantity DESC LIMIT 2
```

I am trying to get the top two products with highest inventory quantity. However, when I test query, it told me that there is syntax error. I remember that works in MySQL but not for this?

Comment: `LIMIT` is a MySQL-specific extension, not part of any official ANSI/ISO SQL standards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

T-SQL does not use the LIMIT clause. Perhaps you want `TOP 2`?

```
SELECT TOP 2 p.id, p.name, pc.categoryName, p.inventoryQuantity FROM dbo.Products p 
INNER JOIN dbo.ProductVariants pv ON pv.product = p.id 
INNER JOIN dbo.ProductCategories pc ON p.productCategory = pc.id 
WHERE pc.categoryName = 'Diary' 
ORDER BY p.inventoryQuantity DESC
```

Comment: But select top 2 does not return me the top 2 products with highest inventory quantity

Comment: Yes, it does, since you have the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: I have 4 product: prod 17 66units, 18 100units, 19 30units, 20 20units. If I select top 1, it returns me the prod 17 with 66units instead of the 100units one. Why?

Comment: What is the data type of the column? Maybe it's varchar or nvarchar and not  number?

Comment: it is varchar(MAX). I cannot change the data type of database tho

Comment: Yes, it matters. The "number" is not a number. The database is sorting it like a character string, and not like a number. Try `ORDER BY CONVERT(INT, p.inventoryQuantity) DESC`

Answer (score 2):

There is Limit Clause rather you should use Select TOP 2

```
SELECT TOP (2) p.id, p.name, pc.categoryName, p.inventoryQuantity FROM dbo.Products p   
INNER JOIN dbo.ProductVariants pv ON pv.product = p.id   
INNER JOIN dbo.ProductCategories pc ON p.productCategory = pc.id  
WHERE pc.categoryName = 'Diary'    
ORDER BY p.inventoryQuantity DESC
```

More information on this can be seen at 'http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx' see limitations and restrictions

Comment: But select top 2 does not return me the top 2 product with highest inventoryQuantity

Comment: SHould work now..The page link i sent you will also explain the concept. See once you order the results from highest to smallest (desc) then the top two would be the highest two

Comment: I have 4 product: prod 17 66units, 18 100units, 19 30units, 20 20units. If I select top 1, it returns me the prod 17 with 66units instead of the 100units one. Why?

Comment: Are you sure the field with the number of units is the one you are sorting by?

Answer (score 0):

LIMIT 2 is not valid, try this:

```
SELECT TOP(2) p.id, p.name, pc.categoryName, p.inventoryQuantity FROM dbo.Products p   
INNER JOIN dbo.ProductVariants pv ON pv.product = p.id   
INNER JOIN dbo.ProductCategories pc ON p.productCategory = pc.id  
WHERE pc.categoryName = 'Diary'    
ORDER BY p.inventoryQuantity DESC
```

Comment: @TMcKwown I have 4 product: prod 17 66units, 18 100units, 19 30units, 20 20units. If I select top 1, it returns me the prod 17 with 66units instead of the 100units one. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this code ..............
If you are using MYSQL database then this query is correct for your requirement.

```
  SELECT p.id, p.name, pc.categoryName, p.inventoryQuantity FROM dbo.Products p 
    INNER JOIN dbo.ProductVariants pv ON pv.product = p.id 
    INNER JOIN dbo.ProductCategories pc ON p.productCategory = pc.id 
    WHERE pc.categoryName = 'Diary' 
    ORDER BY p.inventoryQuantity DESC LIMIT 0,2
```

If you are using T-SQL database then this query is correct for your requirement.

```
SELECT TOP 2 p.id, p.name, pc.categoryName, p.inventoryQuantity FROM dbo.Products p 
    INNER JOIN dbo.ProductVariants pv ON pv.product = p.id 
    INNER JOIN dbo.ProductCategories pc ON p.productCategory = pc.id 
    WHERE pc.categoryName = 'Diary' 
    ORDER BY p.inventoryQuantity DESC
```

Comment: You can not use limit 2 directly rather than you can use above query

Comment: But select top 2 does not return me the top 2 product with highest inventory quantity